# Page shifts in iOS 6 when <input/> text overflows

Tags: css, html, ios6

I have this very strange problem on my website in iOS 6.

On my login screen I have two `<input/>` fields, username and password. I enter text in the `<input/>` fields, if the width of the text is more than the width of the `<input/>` (when the text overflows), the whole screen shifts about `50px` to the bottom right. This happens when I continuously type characters or delete characters using the delete button in virtual keyboard. Once the text width is less than the `<input/>` width, the page isn't shifted. This is happening in iOS 6, Safari, and iOS 6 app.

I tried setting the parent to `overflow: hidden` with no luck.

**How do I prevent the page from shifting when the text overflows in the `<input/>` fields?**

[Here's an example showcasing it.](http://pastehtml.com/view/d2yjcn570.html)

Comment: Could you provide some sample code? Perhaps as a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `position:fixed`? I don't have an iPhone / iPod Touch / iPad so I can't test it.